# Jquery click not working except on firefox

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-chrome, firefox

I have been investigating a lot of methods and can't find a solution, i am defining a on click function on a option element but not working except in firefox,

the code is very simple,

```
<script>
jQuery("#djd_site_post_select_category-1").val('1');

jQuery(".ident-1").click(function() {

alert("click");

});
</script>
```

Solved:
the problem was that i tried to attach click listener to an option tag, which is not valid in google chrome

Comment: Show us some code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: We need to see code, otherwise there is no point.

Comment: sorry for that but the code is very simple

Comment: Is jQuery loaded? user `alert(jQuery)` to test.
What is the output in the console?

Comment: Check if jQuery is loaded and try to attach the click event handler after DOM is loaded - `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // .. your code here }` .. or if this doesn't help show us http://jsfiddle.net/ demo with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    

      jQuery("#djd_site_post_select_category-1").val('1');

             jQuery(".ident-1").click(function() {

                      alert("click");

       }); 
});
```